# Fluttter how to use databinding in FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I add databinding in FlutterFragmentActivity but log issue Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding
This is my code

```
package com.loyalty
  import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
  import android.app.Activity
  import android.content.Intent
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.util.Log
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import com.loyalty.ActivityMainBinding
  import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
  import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

  class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
 }
```

Fluttter how to use databinding in FlutterFragmentActivity

Comment: You are trying to use a native layout in a flutter project. That doesn't make sense